# Input parameters of a function getting as undefined in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, octave

Following is my code in MATLAB and I get the error afterwards no matter what the line is

```
% function for integ midpoint
function result= midpoint(func,a,b,n)
  result=0;
  dx=(b-a)/n;
  for k=0:n-1 %sum of n rectangles
    %m1=a+dx/2
    mp=func(a+(dx/2)+k*dx);
    result=result+mp;
  endfor
  result=result*dx;
endfunction

midpoint(squared,-1,1,10);
```

Error:

```
error: 'b' undefined near line 4 column 7
```

Comment: Hi ov1n, welcome to SO. Chances are you have this code in a single file called `midpoint.m` and you're trying to run it by calling `midpoint` or `midpoint()` in the terminal. Instead, put the function definition _only_ in `midpoint.m` and call `midpoint(squared, -1, 1, 10)` from the terminal. Or, put it in a file called, e.g. `main.m` in the same directory, and then call `main` from the terminal. (Note that you will also need a valid definition for `squared` for this to run, e.g. `squared = @(x) x.^2;` )

Comment: And if this *is* all within the same script, it is only valid in Octave and not MATLAB (which requires functions at the *end* of the script). Likewise for `endfunction`. This is why the tag descriptions discourage using both tags on the same question.